# Error with Annotate Selected Features in ArcGIS Pro 2.1.2

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, annotation

I'm trying complete a script that will automatically create an annotation layer from a feature layer in ArcGIS Pro but am hitting a wall with the "Annotate Selected Features" code block (all information is on the ESRI site here).

Here's my code:

```
import arcpy 
import os 
import os.path 
import sys 
import datetime 

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\myname\Desktop\USACE\Working_Map\Working_map.gdb"  
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Users\myname\Desktop\USACE\Working_Map\Working_Map.aprx")  
m = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]  
lyr = m.listLayers("WGRES_Layer")[0]  

arcpy.AnnotateSelectedFeatures_cartography(m, 'WGRES_Layer', "WGRES_LayerAnno 'Class 1'", 'GENERATE_UNPLACED')
```

Now the weirdest thing is the error message I get when I try to run this block; I get the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 15, in <module> 
AttributeError: module 'arcpy' has no attribute 'AnnotateSelectedFeatures_cartography'
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

I get the same thing if I tried to run the tool as "AnnotateSelectedFeatures" instead (i.e. remove "_cartography" from the end).

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/52390181/820534

Answer (score 3):

The Annotate Selected Features tool was only added to ArcGIS Pro at 2.2.
To use this tool you'll need to update from 2.1.2 to 2.2 or newer.

Reference:  http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/cartography/cartography-toolbox-history-pro.htm

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got our license administrator to allow us to install the update and it's working now. Thanks!